# How to add all objects data in an empty array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I want to club certain records into an empty array, to pass into some function.
So, on check of checkbox component I'm able to get the id of the record which I want to compare it with the array of data. My concern is to push all the checked records to newly created empty array, to pass it to some function. I have gone through various posts but, didn't get any satisfactory result. Please refer to the following code.

```
const newAllData = [{testId:123, dataId:"44", cycleId:"5050", asset:"N"},
{testId:323, dataId:"54", cycleId:"6660", asset:"N"},
{testId:444, dataId:"44", cycleId:"4340", asset:"Y"},
{testId:134, dataId:"40", cycleId:"5150", asset:"N"},
{testId:222, dataId:"42", cycleId:"5050", asset:"Y"},
{testId:552, dataId:"38", cycleId:"3244", asset:"Y"},
]

const [newArray, setNewArray] = useState([])

// Here I get id of the reocord checked
const getArray = (id) => { 
    
    //Here I find that particular record from data above
    const newObj = newAllData?.find(d => d.testId == id);

    var arrayData = [];
    arrayData.push(...newObj);
    setNewArray(arrayData)
  }

  console.log("NEW ARRAY", newArray)
  return <>
  <CheckboxComp getArrayData={getArray} />
  </>;
```

Here only one record is populating in the newArray. What is the right approach to get all the records.

Comment: setNewArray([...newArray ,...arrayData]), ,try this in your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the state with the found object you need to [include the previous state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
setNewArray([...newArray, found]);
```

BUT: you also need to include a condition based on whether the box is checked on or not. If it's checked add it to the state as above. If it's not checked [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it from the `newArray` state.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

// Pass in some data
function App({ data }) {

  // Set the state
  const [ newArray, setNewArray ] = useState([]);

  function handleChange(e) {

    // Get `value` and `checked` from the box
    const { value, checked } = e.target;
    
    // If the box is checked add it to the state
    // Note: we coerce the value to a number from a string
    // because we use a equality check `===`, and the value of
    // `testId` is a number
    if (checked) {
      const found = data.find(obj => obj.testId === +value);
      if (found) setNewArray([...newArray, found]);
    }
    
    // If the box is not checked remove it from the state
    if (!checked) {
      const filtered = newArray.filter(obj => obj.testId !== +value);
      setNewArray(filtered);
    }
  
  }

  // Log the change in state for clarification
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray));
  }, [newArray]);

  return (
    <div>
      <CheckboxComp
        data={data}
        handleChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );

}

function CheckboxComp({ data, handleChange }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(obj => {
        const { testId } = obj;
        return (
          <label for={testId}>
            {testId}
            <input
              name={testId}
              type="checkbox"
              value={testId}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </label>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

const data=[{testId:123,dataId:"44",cycleId:"5050",asset:"N"},{testId:323,dataId:"54",cycleId:"6660",asset:"N"},{testId:444,dataId:"44",cycleId:"4340",asset:"Y"},{testId:134,dataId:"40",cycleId:"5150",asset:"N"},{testId:222,dataId:"42",cycleId:"5050",asset:"Y"},{testId:552,dataId:"38",cycleId:"3244",asset:"Y"}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <App data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
body { font-size: 1.1em; }
label { margin-right: 0.5em; padding: 0.2em; }
label:hover { background-color: #ffffa0; }
[type="checkbox"]:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make and array from object with `Array.from()` method :

```
Array.from(object, (element, index) => { /* … */ } )
```

Answer (score 0):

please assign **var arrayData = [];** in outside the **getArray** function

Answer (score 0):

Your are using `find` in `getArray` function which returns only the first element in the provided array. Try using `filter`.
[Documentation for find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
const getArray = (id) => {
  const checkedItem = newArray.find(item => item.testId === id);
  let targetArr = [];
  if (checkedItem) {
    targetArr = newArray.filter(item => item.testId !== id);
  } else {
    targetArr = [...newArray, checkedItem]
  }
  setNewArray(targetArr)
}
```